# Closing the laptop lid makes my Wifi download slow

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, download, internet-speed, lid

I have windows 8 on a HP Laptop. When I close the lid while downloading "peer to peer" the speed decreases dramatically.

The laptop is not sleeping nor hibernating (I disabled those options), and the hard disk remains active.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I remember on some laptops to exist a button that, upon closing the lid, it became pressed, automatically placing the computer on sleep.
Other than this, remember that "peer to peer" speed is highly relative to the amount of users and their speeds, it might be just coincidental.

Comment: Try to perform a [speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net/) to the same server while lid open and lid closed.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should make a new question because I have a similar issue, but my wifi download speed drops when the screen is off by the power saving mode. I unchecked "allow computer turn off this device to save power" and changed the settings in power management to "Never" except the screen which turns off after 10 minutes. It doesn't happen to the RJ45 connector, only to my wifi. What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer in the forum below solved this problem for me.
As I understand it, closing the lid changes the antennae angle (because they are in the lid), thereby affecting the ability to receive the wifi signal.

In short the solution is to close the lid then prop the computer vertically (hinge down) by leaning it against a wall or other item. Seems odd, but has worked for me.

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Wireless-Internet-Home-Networking/WiFi-Signal-Degradation-with-Laptop-Lid-Closed/td-p/899177

Comment: This actually helped me with my Lenovo closed. When I closed the lid to work and attached my laptop on a flat screen. I thought it was some lag with the HDMI cable. Turns out the wifi reception is distorted by closing the lid. Thanks